# Tor + Urllib2 Python

Tags: python, urllib2, tor

I am trying to use tor to get a new IP every time I access a website:

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, '127.0.0.1', 9151, True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen("http://almien.co.uk/m/tools/net/ip/").read()
```

I have also tried port 9150, 9050 too.

I keep getting:

```
socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS4 proxy 127.0.0.1:9151: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: Make sure your Tor browser is open before connecting to it through the script. You can automatise this by including something like `os.system('open /Applications/TorBrowser.app')` -or whatever path where you have Tor- in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [stem](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stem/1.4.1) package to interact with Tor. Official site have many [tutorials](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials.html) for different cases, for example:

https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html